# High PageIOLatch_SH Waits with High Drive Idle times

Tags: sql-server, windows

We are experiencing high volume of PageIOLatch_SH waits on our database (row counts in the Billions).  However it seems that our drive Idle time Percentage hovers around 50-60 percent.  CPU usage is nill.  The Database Tuning Advisor gives no suggestions for optimization.  The query plan (actual) from the single stored procedure used on the database puts the majority of the expense on index seek (yeah I know these should be optimial) operations.

Anyone have suggestions of how to increase throughput?

Comment: Can you give us more details on the IO subsystem, DAS, SAN, iSCSI etc. Bandwidth to it, disk queue lengths.

Comment: Are the estimated row counts lower than the actual row counts?

Comment: Any SQL or Windows error log messages? What is the full plan too please? Last index rebuild/statistics update?

Comment: I believe the read queue seemed a little high on the non idle drives when the idle spikes down to 0 (short term).  No error messages in windows

Comment: not much in the way I can give you about Subsystem besides DAS.

Answer (score 3):

Is there memory pressure on your server? The buffer pool may be filling up causing a lot of paging out to disk.

```
SELECT cntr_value AS [Page Life Expectancy]
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] = N'SQLServer:Buffer Manager'
AND counter_name = N'Page life expectancy' OPTION (RECOMPILE);

-- Is this a NUMA system?
SELECT
  CASE COUNT(DISTINCT parent_node_id)
     WHEN 1
         THEN 'NUMA disabled'
         ELSE 'NUMA enabled'
  END
FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers
WHERE parent_node_id NOT IN (32, 64);
```

Also, check the number of rows returned and the hierarchy in your where statements. You may be returning more rows than you require.

Comment: Memory seems more than sufficient (124GB).

Comment: @MartyTrenouth I've edited a query in to StanleyJohns answer to check PLE and just in case, to confirm if this is a NUMA system. Can you add the output to your question please.

Comment: Page Life 717, NUMA disabled

Comment: That's low, very low for a 124GB buffer pool.

Comment: Agree 717 is low PLE by anyone's standards

Comment: query used, makes a interation call (10K batches) on a primary table of 1.3B records for distributed processing.  I'm not too surprised that SQL is hitting low PageLife.

Comment: Right, a quick search of StackOverflow indicates maybe poor indexing in that case. 1.3 billion in 124GB buffer pool? Wide table? BLOBs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620626/what-is-pageiolatch-sh-wait-type-in-sql-server/620654#620654

Comment: @MartyTrenouth 1) this is your 2nd question on dba.se but you've cast ZERO votes. 2) You're missing gbn, stanley and my point - you have latch waits because PLE is low, because you're churning the buffer pool.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith 1) I understand PLE is low and caused by churning the pool, but what can I do to increase PLE on random access to three tables with ~200MM - 1B rows.  I added filtered indexes on the non random access tables.  2) Up voteed Stanley's query for identifying the PLE, but remember this is only my SECOND question forwarded from SO.

Comment: @MartyTrenouth You'll need to give us more to work with. Pop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) and we can go dig into the details you need to add to your question to get useful answers.